# New Server Query AD is giving permission error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

We replaced a physical server with virtual, I copied all the logins, and linked servers from the old server and restored all the databases from the old server to the new.  Everything works fine except for a query that uses a linked server to query Active directory.  I get a permission error:

```
The OLE DB provider "ADSDSOObject" for linked server "ADSI" reported an error. The provider indicates that the user did not have the permission to perform the operation.
```

If I go to the linked server and test connection it succeeds.  The linked server is set to connect to AD using SQLService.  The only think that changed is the physical box we were running on, so it has to be something on the sql side that is not configured correctly?

Comment: Is RPC OUT enabled in the "ASDI" Linked Server's settings?  I get this error when that's disabled sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

I would presume the server Adam service GUID changed and or need to create a new computer object for your (virtual) as it's associated with the physical (adsi).

Presuming you've done all the user, machine creation. Perhaps run a com lime logo to confirm the ticket is valid database service and machine etc.?

Objects in ADS is what I'd audit and confirm. 
Command kinit

Answer (score 0):

Appears as though my DOMAIN\SQLService account had gotten locked out somehow on AD, as soon as that was unlocked it started working fine.